# ion-list-header background is not gray on iOS

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic.io

I am using a code like this in ionic 2.0.0rc4

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-list-header>My Header</ion-list-header>
  <!-- rest of ion-items -->
</ion-list>
```

In the documentation examples, list header's background is gray but in my app it has a white background! I don't know what is going on!

Any idea?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation, following SASS variable is used to set the list header background for ios `$list-ios-header-background-color` and its default value is `transparent`.

If you look closely, in the documentation also, color is coming grey for iOS and white for android & windows phone.

hope this helps.